# Namespace error in yii2 controller

Tags: php, yii2

I want to make a installation script for my app in yii2 and for that I want to redirect it to a `defaultRoute='installation/index'` but I am getting this namespace error when I have right namespace in my installation controller

Also I have a Installation model which does not extends to the `activerecords` and is used to get the user input values and perform some actions without the need of saving them into DB but it's directory is also not found.

[image: Below is the error I am getting]

*Installation controller code:*

```
namespace livecrm\controllers;

class InstallationController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

*install-config.php:*

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'app-livecrm',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],

    'defaultRoute' => '/installation/index',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'JDqkJaMgIITAKcsJY6yvLQdM9jf7WghX',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'livefactory\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
return $config;
```

*config/main.php:*

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../livefactory/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../livefactory/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [



    'id' => 'app-livecrm',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'livecrm\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [

        'gii' => [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.0.*', '*'] // adjust this to your needs
],

     'gridview' => [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\Module',
        ],

         'liveobjects' => [
            'class' => 'livefactory\modules\liveobjects\Module',
        ],
         'pmt' => [
            'class' => 'livefactory\modules\pmt\Module',
        ],
         'user' => [
            'class' => 'livefactory\modules\user\Module',
        ],
         'sales' => [
            'class' => 'livefactory\modules\sales\Module',
        ],
         'customer' => [
            'class' => 'livefactory\modules\customer\Module',
        ],
        'product' => [
            'class' => 'livefactory\modules\product\product',
        ],
        'cron' => [
            'class' => 'livefactory\modules\cron\Module',
        ],


    ],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'livefactory\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'authManager'=>[
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'defaultRoles' =>['guest'],
        ],
        'as access' => [
            'class' => 'mdm\admin\components\AccessControl',
            'allowActions' => [
                'site/*', // add or remove allowed actions to this list
            ]
        ],
    ],

    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: show some code of the controller

Comment: @ankitraturi added controller code

Comment: Hi deepak. it's really hard for us to read your screenshot of code. Could you please instead edit your question and copy/paste your code into your question instead?

Comment: That will also help us by letting us copy out the relevant bits with an error and making changes and posting it as an answer for you...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using basic application template.

The namespace of controller for your case should be:

```
namespace app\controllers\InstallationController;
```

The error message is very clear by the way and tells exactly about that.

**Update:** If you need namespace different than `app\controllers` you can change it through `controllerNamespace` property of `yii\base\Applcation`. For example you can add this to your config:

```
'controllerNamespace' => 'livecrm\\controllers',
```

**Official docs:**

- [$controllerNamespace](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$controllerNamespace-detail)

Comment: but all other code of my app is using namespace livecrm/controllers.So I wanted to use the same for this controller also

Comment: its based on advanced template and if I change namespace to app/controller then I have to change it all over in the code which is not possible.I will update my ques with config/main.php where I have used default controller namespace as livecrm/controllers

Comment: 'controllerNamespace' => 'livecrm\controller' is already done in my main.php config file.I have added code of main.php

Comment: try `'livecrm\\controllers'` instead of `'livecrm\controllers'`

Comment: @ankitraturi still the same error with 'livecrm\\controllers'